# php tags in js file generating "Unexpected token error in console log

Tags: javascript, jquery, zen-cart

I'm upgrading my Zencart based website to version 1.5.7 and a module that previously worked perfectly is now broken.

On inspecting the console log I'm seeing " Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' "
The code line where it reports this error is in a js file

```
var session_language_id = <?php echo $_SESSION['languages_id']; ?>;
```

I've got other instances of the same error in different files and it's always where a <?php tag has been used inside a script.

Given that this should be a valid code format, can anyone shed any light on what might be causing this issue as it's got me stumped!

Comment: you can view the full error by going to the specific line where the mentioned code is executing in your page

Comment: this error might be coming from PHP and showing PHP error and that's why javascript is not recognizing the syntax

Comment: @HelloWorl, yes I know. I already did this which is how I know it's the php  tags throwing the error. They have a red squiggly underline with a cross mark at the end of the line.
Question is, what would cause it suddenly decide it doesn't like php tags in code that previously worked perfectly well.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' ` this error you mentioned is a javascript error, you need to show the error caused by `<?php echo $_SESSION['languages_id']; ?>` <-- this block of code

Comment: another way you can check the error by adding the whole id inside of quote(') like this: `var session_language_id = "<?php echo $_SESSION['languages_id']; ?>";` and console log the `session_language_id` variable after that line like this: `console.log(session_language_id)`. this way you can get the php error logged in the console